# Find if remote directory has been changed (git)?

Tags: git

Is it possible to find out if a remote directory has been changed since the last pull?

Or get the modification date/time of a remote directory?

Comment: try to push something. It must throw an error :p

Comment: Why not `git fetch` and then peek at the latest commit on `origin/master`?

Comment: Do you actually mean a specific (sub-)Directory, or a specific Branch? * To check a (sub-)directory you will need to `git fetch` the appropriate branch and then compare your local copy with the one you now have in you remote/refs * `git branch -vv` will give you the ahead/behind status.

Answer (score 0):

You can verify if the remote repository is up to date by comparing some remote reference with the corresponding local reference. Here the master branch is used as an example.

```
$ git ls-remote -h origin
647183ae2208309097fc1dacd13b8568b1d651cc  refs/heads/master
$ cat .git/refs/remotes/origin/master
bb5781a9bc077333d7f8cdfecf33364dcd861b2d
```

A better approach is to use fetch+merge instead of pull. Fetch will only update origin/master. Then you can see if you want to merge or not before continuing.

```
$ git fetch  # Will not affect any of your private branches.
$ git merge origin/master
```